# Airflow Subdag tasks backfill in CLI is creating new tasks instead of rerunning the failed tasks and only running 1 day not range

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to do the backfill in the command line, I'm launching the backfill command on ECS Fargate and instead of rerunning the tasks for the subdag for 2021-01-03 its creating new tasks for 2021-01-02 and running it, and if I try to do a range 2021-01-03 to  2021-01-05 it only runs for one date

```
    ./launch-ecs-backfill.sh -v -w -t dev 'instagram.build_media -s 2021-01-03
 -e 2021-01-05 --rerun-failed-tasks'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I had to add the exact time of the start date so it would instead be this for the start and end:

```
 -s 2021-01-01T10:00:00+00:00 -e 2021-01-03T10:00:00+00:00
```